# Why am I facing this error: File to import not found or unreadable: ./styles-variables?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular7

I am following this tutorial:
https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/how-to-build-responsive-layouts-with-bootstrap-4-and-angular-6-cfbb108d797b

I reached the point where I have to import styles-variables.scss in the styles file.
However, I keep getting this error:

> ERROR in ./src/app/header/header.component.scss Module build failed
>   (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
>
> @import './styles-variables';   ^
>         File to import not found or unreadable: ./styles-variables.
>         in C:\Users\A.G STRANGER\Desktop\MEAN    stack\bootstrap_second_step\angular-bootstrap-
>   example\src\app\header\header.component.scss (line 1, column 1)   i
>   ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

This is the project structure:
[image]

Anyone has any idea where did I make a mistake?
Thank yoou!

Comment: There is no file `./styles-variables` in `app/header`... it is written just there ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, your relative path is just a bit off.

`"../../styles-variables"`

Also, make sure that, that file is included in the `styles` array of your `angular.json` file or Angular won't include it into your output.

Answer (score 0):

In `angular.json`, there is a way to have a directory for your variables to beat.

Place this in your `angular.json` appName => build,

```
"options": {
    ...,
    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": [
            "./src/sass"
        ]
    },
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you please explain why should I do that?

Comment: To avoid relative paths

Comment: Any idea if in Angular 7 we have to add this to the server options too? I'm using Angular Universal and it builds correctly for the browser, but not for the server side.

Comment: We weren’t doing server side rendering thus I don’t have any idea, try it and share it.